# How to fix Network Response Timed Out when Using Expo on Windows?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

[image]

I am using same wifi network.. I checked my ip address, but I don't understand how to get same build output on same network address

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I change connection barcode tunnel. previous it was LAN [image]